# Background image need to "stretch" on scroll down instead of staying static?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a background image which seems to be static on my website and when I scroll down it keeps scrolling with the page... I want the top to stay static and then when I scroll down for the rest of the page to appear as #FFFFFF...

`html, body{background:#ffffff url(images/background-repx.png) repeat-x;height:100%;min-height:100%;}`

Any ideas how to do this, I'm not familiar with CSS backgrounds.

Thanks in advance
- Hyflex

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
background:#000000 url(<img>) no-repeat scroll center top;
```

To see this effect, using chrome, change the css to:

```
background:#FFFFFF url(<img>) no-repeat scroll center top;
```

Which sets a background colour AND image, places the image statically at the top, so that after scrolling down, the background colour is only visible.

Comment: the problem with that is that it doesn't repeat horizontally (the image is a sliter) and it needs to be repeated to make the image full across the top.